# Is SE enforcing "no answers in comments"?

Tags: discussion, comments, policy

The practice of commenting with answers is ubiquitous practice on ELU, and the merits/flaws have been discussed at length. However, is it the case that the greater SE is trying to put a stop to this practice? This [removed comment](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/1272/how-to-respond-to-trivial-obvious-questions#comment3881_1272) suggests to me that this might be the case.

> (comments removed) If you have an answer, please post it below. Comments do not have the feature to properly vet whatever you say here so without activity like proper voting and wiki-style editing of content, answering here defeats the purpose of having this Stack Exchange site. – [Robert Cartaino ♦](https://stackexchange.com/users/34933/robert-cartaino)

Edit: I'm not levelling judgement on the practice here, I'm just curious.

Comment: Related: [Answers in comments](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11326/).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There is no new initiative to eliminate answers in comment. They have always been discouraged.

The purpose of Stack Exchange is to get expert, peer-reviewed answers to good questions out on search engines for the benefit of the asker and anyone else with a similar question. Answers in comments cannot be downvoted. Lacking full peer review, they are are really not so helpful to the author as you might think.

Answers in comment are also not indexed by search engines, so they don’t attract future visitors nearly as much as an actual answer post. And, while they might stick around for years, you never know when comments will be silently purged from a question. Comments are truly local and transient. So an answer in comment might never help anybody else.

This is why Robert Cartaino objected to the answers in comment on the post you linked.

Comment threads actually exist to let people

> “request clarification from the author; leave constructive criticism that guides the author in improving the post; [or] add relevant but minor or transient information to a post (e.g. a link to a related question, or an alert to the author that the question has been updated”.
>   [¹](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment)

The help page I’m quoting here goes on to say that “comments are not recommended for:

> “… answering a question or providing an alternate solution to an existing answer; instead, post an actual answer (or edit to expand an existing one)”

All this being said, it is also true that this site gets its share of off-topic questions that will soon get closed and deleted – questions which will never be helpful to future visitors anyway. Some of our experts will often post a quick comment on such a question, when they see an opportunity to informally help the author. This practice has always been tolerated, and I personally don’t see a reason to discourage it.

Comment: +1 Also, when I post partial answers in comments, it's that I hope other users can use that information and write their own detailed answers, which would then be subject to peer reviews.

Comment: @NVZ It's also officially encouraged to post partial answers as answers so that the information you put out there can be peer reviewed.

Comment: @NVZ For example in the help on [writing a good answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) a partial answer is specifically encouraged. Partial answers still help people.

Comment: Ah, thanks for that hint. I was under the assumption that answers without enough backup are deleted. That is what I have seen happen for some time now.

Comment: @NVZ I expect it will help to explain in a partial answer that it *is* a partial answer or a draft answer so that it won't get jumped on.

Comment: I've noticed some users [moving an aggregation of comment-answers into a community-wiki answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/403914/228732).  Is this good practice?  I'm not sure if this has already been discussed on Meta.  I didn't see any mention of it [here](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4224/how-to-handle-old-questions-with-answers-stuck-in-a-comment/5112#5112).

Comment: @MetaEd, like NVZ, I too have noticed a disparity between that policy and how it is enforced. It might be worth being more explicit about how to format the partial answer (such as you've suggested above) in the actual help center topic, as I'd imagine not many users are going to stumble upon it here.

Comment: [Here's](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/404263/142322) a test-balloon for whether partial answers are acceptable by the current ELU community. It's somewhat fuller than a pure answer-in-comments, but I don't consider it to fully answer the OP's question. If in comments, the 2 examples *might* have just been given as links.

Comment: @vpn Consistent enforcement is not the SE model. Which sounds like a weird thing to say, and probably deserves its own meta question.

Comment: @MetaEd, I have no clue what that means, but oh well.

Comment: @Lawrence, if that's considered a partial answer, I'd hate to see what a full answer is.

Comment: @vpn Haha, thanks. The question asks "*Why singular?*" My partial answer is something like *that's just how it is*. A full answer would justify *why* the singular is used, not just *that* it is (usually) used.

Comment: Regarding prospective harm in the last case, there are at least a couple of considerations. The first is that it circumvents the goal of closure if people can publish their opinions regardless, and disincentives improvement to the question that would make it answerable. This breaks the intended vote to close, improve and reopen cycle. Also, comments that some people may consider useful to preserve as answers get wiped away by the community bot,  *sometimes as the result of intentional abuse*, since the system is designed to make it harder to delete questions otherwise. Due process is bypassed!

Comment: Can you please make clear that you're not here endorsing the posting of  unsupported/undersupported // conjectural responses as 'answers' (I hope that this is actually the case)? If this is the case, aren't 'comments' the natural place to give such responses, where it is found difficult to find supporting evidence?

Comment: Update to the test-balloon. 2 upvotes and 1 downvote, all comments to the answer deleted. (The comments were more relevant on this thread anyway.)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Are you concerned that SE's policy of encouraging partial answers might be misunderstood to mean encouraging uneducated guesses or shots in the dark?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Also I think the source matters. Most likely, conjectural responses from the John Lawlers of this site would be helpful.

Comment: (a) Yes; that seems to be how Lawrence is employing a wedge. (b) Agreed, but (b1) most conjectural responses I've seen just draw the site into mediocrity but can be popular, and policing on this site is far from adequate; (b2) the metaphorical broadening of John Lawler (the acceptability of the pluralisation) is sadly confined to the realms of mythology.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Policing of the site deserves its own meta question. I will rant, though, that as a moderator it is disappointing to see how many questions show up in the moderator flag queue with NO DOWN VOTES. Not even by the person flagging the post.

Comment: @MetaEd I'm not as familiar with ELU's guidance as I am with StackOverflow's, but there the most common response seems to be "_flag or downvote_" ... and only occasionally with a "_or both_" thrown in.

Comment: @MetaEd it's that, when I find that something is flag-worthy, I usually don't care to vote on it as well. It's either 'flag' or 'vote' from me, and only in some rare cases, 'both'.

Comment: @MetaEd: You say, “It’s also officially encouraged to post partial answers as answers so that the information you put out there can be peer reviewed.”  Do you have an official source for this?  It seems to contradict [“We are looking for definitive answers written at an expert level, with explanation and context. Think along the lines of a short essay.”](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/144930/26083#comment899865_381941) Answers with fewer than 200 words and three links routinely get ripped to shreds in the Low Quality Posts queue.

Comment: And actually, [comments **are** indexed by Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Aenglish.stackexchange.com+%22we+don%27t+object+to+someone+giving+a+solution%22) — you may be thinking of [SE]’s search function, which is of very limited utility.

Comment: Would you consider [this linked comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/405692/how-do-you-say-to-brown-bag-it-in-your-neck-of-the-woods#comment965631_405692) to be worth posting as an answer or better left as a comment? Or should we vote to delete the question on the basis of lack of research? By 'lack of research', I'm referring to the 'let me google it for you' variant.

Comment: @Scott I would think that an incomplete answer written just to see if it gets down-voted would be not acceptable. It seems more a _Let's see if  writing an answer is worth my time, or I am wasting it writing something other users don't like._ Answering the question with something more complete, and then researching for more data, is IMO more what I would expect. For example, I could answer about the usage of a word, and then write more with what I found in a corpus of English words.

Comment: @MetaEd How about answering in actual answers but commenting it out so no one can see it? Is that a reasonable alternative to answering in comments?

Comment: @Mitch - I don't understand "commenting it out."  Could you explain?

Comment: @aparente001 look at the edit history of this answer. There's some text that was edited in, but it is in html comment format so you can't read it on this page.

Comment: @Mitch - I looked at the edit history but all I see is a new footnote with an external link (external in the sense that the footnote text doesn't appear within the answer itself).  Could you post a screenshot of what you're talking about?

Comment: @aparente001 [Revision 4](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/10647/revisions)

Comment: @aparente001 you may need to choose the "side-by-side markdown" option to see the significant amount of text in the answer that does not normally appear on the page due to the HTML tags surrounding it.

Answer (score 9):

I need to write this in an answer because — although it might be a comment — it needs an image and I can't decide what actually to add a comment to.

**Please do not flag "for moderator attention" comments which you feel should really be answers.** If a comment shouldn't be there, use the "chatty or otherwise unnecessary" flag type:

[image: Comment dialog]

Answering in comments is something the community can police for itself: if three users feel a comment should not be present and use this flag type, the system removes the comment. It really does not need moderators to do that.

Moderators *do* see these "no longer needed" flags, but the community can also help to deal with them. Answering in comments is not something that *only* moderators can deal with, which is what the last option is for.

Answer (score 1):

The comment you linked in your question is for a site that is in public beta phase. When sites are in private beta phase, or public beta phase, it's normal for Stack Exchange staff, especially Community Coordinators, to chime in and close questions or remove comments. That is because, in those phases, a site doesn't normally have moderators, who are normally appointed later in the public beta phase.

The fact a Community Coordinator removed comments doesn't mean that suddenly comments are not welcome on Stack Exchange. As the privilege page for [*comment everywhere*](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) says, comments are temporary notes, which should be used for specific purposes:

> - Request clarification from the author
> - Leave constructive criticism that guides the author in improving the post
> - Add relevant but minor or transient information to a post (e.g. a link to a related question, or an alert to the author that the question has been updated)

They should **not** be used for the following:

> - Suggesting corrections that don't fundamentally change the meaning of the post; instead, make or suggest an edit
> - Answering a question or providing an alternate solution to an existing answer; instead, post an actual answer (or edit to expand an existing one)
> - Compliments which do not add new information ("+1, great answer!")
> - Criticisms which do not add anything constructive ("-1, see previous comments you scallywag!")
> - Secondary discussion or debating a controversial point
> - Discussion of community behavior or site policies

In particular, long discussions trigger an automatic flag for moderators of the site (which, for a beta site, normally are Community Coordinators) who can remove the comments, or move them to a chat room, if they feel the comments should be preserved for a bit longer.

As for answers given as comments, Stack Exchange is not enforcing the *no answers as comment* policy. Clearly, in a Q&A site, the continuous use of comments to write an answer, especially when done from more users at the same time and for the same question, would be problematic, since:

- Comments cannot be down-voted
- Comments cannot be accepted
- Comments are hard to read, especially when there are many comments

Stack Exchange aims to be a repository of knowledge. It would not be possible to achieve this if blatantly wrong answers are at the same level with other answers, and if the OP would not be able to accept an answer. So, yes, Stack Exchange doesn't like much answers given as comments.
That is also one of the reasons why users are able to comment on questions asked by other users much later than they are able to write an answer. They give the ability to write comments when users possibly understood when to use comments. In a site in beta phase, where the reputation necessary to comment and do other things is lower than in sites out of the beta phase.

That said, there are cases where you can see users writing answers in comments, probably because:

- They don't have the time to write more complete answer, and they want to give a hint for somebody else to write a complete answer
- They want to understand what exactly the OP is asking
- They think the question should be closed, but they want to help a little the OP

Comment: I strongly endorse the policy 'don't write answers as comments.' When I see myself doing this I will either post it as an answer instead or simply delete my comment.

Comment: I normally don't see the need of Answers written as comments. If I want to be sure I understand what the OP wants, or found, I rather explicitly ask; if I think the question should be closed, I don't write an answer in any shape, or the OP could get the habit to ask bad questions; if I don't have the time to answer, I don't have the time to comment too. That doesn't mean I don't see any reason for users to write answers in comments, though.

Comment: I fully agree with your reasons not to post answers as comments. There is one other incentive that reputation-minded members might keep in mind: answers can earn rep, unlike comments!

Comment: @EnglishStudent Yes, and many of us with high reps answer in comments to prevent further growth. Plus, most of the questions can be answered in a couple sentences, and most of those are just random errors that no one else will ever find or use. The idea of looking at ELU  as "a repository of knowledge" is downright ludicrous.

Comment: @JohnLawler If a question is about errors nobody else will make/find, the question can be closed.